# Is it possible for a web based app to retrive images from an iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, image

I'm creating a website which I would like to be supported on the iphone as well. The site allows users to upload images and manipulate them. On a desktop the user will simply click the upload button to select the file from their computer and upload it to the site. But this will fail on an iphone.

Is there any way for a pure web app which is using php/mysql/js and runs inside the browser to get images from a user's camera roll? Does Apple offer any APIs to make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible currently - but apparently iOS 6 is going to support image and video uploads from MobileSafari.
(Apart from that, you can ask your users if their device is jailbroken and id so, suggest them downloading Safari Upload Enabler from Cydia).